# SQL Server within & using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

Trying to create a asp.net c# form for learning purposes at home and i'm absolutely struggling to connect to my storedprocedure.

I'm definitely in the right database as when I start the database by cmdprompt and connect to it via datasource in visual design it connects and finds the stored procedure. So there must be something I am doing wrong? I've been searching Google for about 30-40 minutes now and everything I've tried hasn't resolved my issue. Any suggestions please?

```
const string constring = @"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";

    public static int InsertEnquiry(string Name, string Subject, string Email, string Message, string Phone) {

        //default ticketid of 0 which will be changed to -1 if an error or greater than 0 if successful
        int TicketID = 0;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone)) Phone = "0";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constring)) {
            //create command
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            //tell the command which connection its using
            command.Connection = conn;

            //inform command that it is a stored procedure and the name of stored procedure
            command.CommandText = "InsertEnquiry";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //add the parameters to the sqlcommand
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Name;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Subject;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Phone;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Email;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Message;

            // try run command and set TicketID to the row inserted into the table.
            try {
                conn.Open();
                //run command
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //return scope identity of row.
                TicketID = (int)command.Parameters["@TicketID"].Value;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //show -1 to state there is an error
                TicketID = -1;
            }
        }

        return TicketID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a MSDN article. You may need to scroll down. [Using Parameters With a SqlCommand and a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2013 version.... we have SQL Server 2012 and 2014 .... which one are you using?

Comment: sorry - its visual express 2013 using sql server within - i'll amend the title if possible.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Could not find stored procedure 'InsertEnquiry'.

Comment: Use schema qualified name, like `command.CommandText = "dbo.InsertEnquiry";` or appropriate schema in which `InsertEnquiry` was created.

Comment: it is dbo schema - from what i gathered it was default set to dbo if not supplied - but i gave it a go anyway and came with "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.InsertEnquiry'." error - its almost as if it doesnt exist, but it definitely does i can see it and its spelt correctly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st
I think you are connected to the wrong db, probably you are in master.
Run this piece of code and check the name of the database and see if it's the one that you want.

```
public static string checkDB()
{
    string dbName = "";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        //create command
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        //tell the command which connection its using
        command.Connection = conn;

        //inform command that it is a stored procedure and the name of stored procedure
        command.CommandText = "select DB_NAME()";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // try run command and set TicketID to the row inserted into the table.
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            //run command
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            dbName = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    return dbName;
}
```

2nd
You are trying to get the value from the parameter @TicketID but you didn't specify this parameter as an output parameter.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@TicketID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

**EDIT1:**
This is how do you put the db name in the connection string:

```
const string constring = @"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial Catalog=MY_DB_NAME";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just knew I was missing something! You were right - it wasn't connecting to the right catalog.